# Android Studio doesn't build the project after removing git

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build

I have an android project and it had some git issues so I removed git from it using:

```
rm -rf .git
```

By going into the project directory.

And then reinstalled git using:

```
git init
```

but now on android studio the option to build the project does not work, I tried hammer icon, make project button but nothing happens by clicking on it. 
I have android studio version 3.5.1.

Then I tried creating a new project, it works fine and builds.

Here is the screenshot of my screen, with project that doesn't build.
[image]

Comment: i have made some minor changes to your question for grammar and to make the question title a bit clearer, if you have any issues feel free to let me know and i will rollback these changes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with

`File->Sync Project With Gradle Files`, option.

It worked, but don't know why.